# Sigma-fields and probability

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, random-variables

[image]

I'm unsure what this question asks of me. For (i) I have given a power set with 16 elements in terms of a,b,c and d. I don't understand what I need to do for (ii). I believe (iii) is fairly self-explanatory, and requires me to use (ii) and the probabilities given. Is this correct?

Comment: $\sigma(X) = \{X^{-1}(B) \subseteq \Omega: B \in \mathcal B\}$, where $\mathcal B$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. For example, if $1 \in B$ and $-1 \notin B$, then $X^{-1}(B) = \{a,b\} \in \sigma(X)$. Can you do the rest?

Answer (score 0):

For (ii), the $\sigma$-algebra generated by a random variable $X$ is the set
$$\sigma(X) = \{X^{-1}(B) : B\in\mathcal B\}, $$
where $\mathcal B$ is the borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb R$ (it is a good exercise to show that this is in face a $\sigma$-algebra). So for example, $X^{-1}(\varnothing)=\varnothing$ and $X^{-1}(\mathbb R)=\{a,b,c,d\}$, so $\varnothing,\Omega\in\sigma(X)$. The other sets in $\sigma(X)$ can be found by taking e.g. $X^{-1}(\{1\})$ and $X^{-1}(\{-1\})$.

For (iii), the formal definition of conditional expectation is that $\mathbb E[Y|X]$ is a random variable satisfies
$$ \int_E \mathbb E[Y|\sigma(X)]\mathsf d\mathbb P = \int_E Y\mathsf d\mathbb P$$
for all $E\in\sigma(X)$. The reason for the $\sigma(X)$ in the above equation is that conditional expectation is really defined for a sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal H\subset\mathcal F$ and not for a random variable (but for convenience we write $\mathbb E[Y|X]$ instead of $\mathbb E[Y|\sigma(X)]$. So from this definition we have for example
$$\int_\Omega Z\mathsf d\mathbb P = \int_\Omega Y\mathsf d\mathbb P = \mathbb E[Y] = -\frac16. $$
To actually compute the conditional expectation, you need to compute the above for the other elements of $\sigma(X)$.